# Ordering test according to when they were executed in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

We are using Visual Studio 2008.

We have a solution with ca. 1000 tests. We run the tests from a script which produces a trx file.

Two of our tests timeout, due to what looks like a database lock. When we run the tests alone, they run fine.

How can we findout which tests were run just before the ones that are getting the timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the test results tool window right click on the grid headers, that allows you to add the Start Time column. Click on that column to sort by start time.

Comment: Thanks it was a [TestCleanup()] tag that had been commented out, causing a transaction to hang.